# Named parameter with underscore in Dart class

Tags: dart, flutter

From the Dart language tour you can do this:

```
class Person {
  final _name;

  const Person(this._name);
}
```

How can I get a named parameter like this:

```
class Person {
  final _name;

  const Person({@required this._name});
}
```

So the usage will be:

```
const Person(name: 'SD')
```

I still want a `const` constructor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can, but not with the `this.variable` syntax

```
const Person({ String name}) : _name = name;
```

Comment: Just curious as a beginner to this language, what is the advantage of having underscore at the beginning of the named parameter?

Comment: They are private, which means they are not accessible from outside of the file.

Comment: "outside of the file" from a practical sense.  However, technically it's "library visible", so if you're using `part` / `part of` it would be visible to the entire library.  However, that's discouraged officially now, and is used only for builders that need to use generated code.

Comment: Well trying to keep things simple. If we wanted to go full details, we'd have to speak about `export` directive too for example.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unnamed parameter

If you don't want to see the underscore for an unnamed parameter, you can do the following:

```
class Person {

  final _name;

  Person(String name) : _name = name;

}
```

Then when people type, it will autocomplete to this:

```
Person(name)
```

instead of this:

```
Person(_name)
```